# Sanitise bash arguments

Tags: bash, security

I have a script which takes user input and does a lot of things. One thing which I am worried about is it takes a file name and removes that file. e.g. rm -rf $arg1.

A user could technically input / in this arg and break things. How do I make it so I escape all symbols (my requirement is just letters and numbers as everything happens in one dir) before I actually execute the rm command.

I have come up with an `echo "$name" | grep -v symbols > $newname`

I'm not sure if this is a good way of doing it. What are your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check with grep (for `/` and `*`):

   ```
   if echo "$user_cmd" | grep '*\|\/'; then
   ...
   fi
   ```
2. BUT.... you should probably treat this as a permissions issue instead. Assign users who use the script to a group with locked-down permissions. This would be better than just stripping characters as a period (`.`) could be used for both a file extension (`.JPG` ) and `../../`